# jQuery - Need to adapt sortable to move multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, sorting

I have a series of elements dynamically created in an element. The idea would be to create sections and sub sections so you could have this on the page:

Header1

-Header2

--Header3

--Header3

-Header2

---Header3

Now, the goal would be that you can sort these all by dragging and dropping them (no problem). So that I could sort multiple Header1s within the body, then within each Header1 sort all Header2s, and within each Header2 sort all Header3s.

I originally accomplished this by using wrapping containers for each header, so that each Header of the descending tier could be sorted, but only within itself, which caused problems. So my new approach was to just make each one on it's own in one big sortable. The issue is, I want it so that if I click and drag a Header2, all Header3s below it move with it, but not any other Header2s or Header1s. This should also apply to Header1s.

I tried the jQuery plugin multisortable, but that only sort of works. It only works for Header1s and all children, not for Header2s and it's children.

I can easily say which elements to move, but I can't figure out how to make them move at the same time.

Any thoughts, plugins, etc.?

**EDIT**

For the sake of example. and to help with the visualization, I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WvQEj/) and some demo code. All I want is to make something like this sort down to three levels:

```
<ul>
    <li class="h1">Header 1</li>
    <li class="h2">Header 2</li>
    <li class="h3">Header 3</li>
    <li class="h3">Header 3</li>
    <li class="h2">Header 2</li>
    <li class="h3">Header 3</li>
    <li class="h1">Header 1</li>
    <li class="h2">Header 2</li>
    <li class="h3">Header 3</li>
</ul>
```

In this example, I want it so that if you move a red, all the greens under it move with it, and if you move a blue, all the reds (and greens) move with it.

Comment: can you provide some code?, maybe a JSFiddle ?

Comment: I was hesitant to provide any code because it doesn't really matter. I have no working code so a JSFiddle is not practical. The only code I would display is an un-ordered list with 3 different classes of li's. If that would still be beneficial, I'll add it it in.